# Spring boot application not able to find sequence in AWS Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, hibernate

In existing spring boot application I have created new entity and for the primary key for this entity I have use annotation @GeneratedValue.
Based on entity and annotation I have created required table and sequence in the Postgresql database.(Note, Spring boot and database are existing)
However, while starting spring boot application I am getting error "Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory Schema-validation: missing sequence", and sequence are created in database under the required schema.

Spring boot application to identify the sequence created in Postgresql and start the application.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgresql DB table, we need to provide privilege (like, insert, delete update) to the user through which spring boot application will connect with DB. So that spring boot application can performed actions like read/write in table/sequence.
For example: DB user mention in application.properties file is dbuser/password, in spring boot application. Then make sure in Postgresql DB side this user, dbuser, should be owner of the the table and have access like, insert, update, delete.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).